# Сравнить элемент а с элементами матрицы в каждой строке

Tags: masm32, masm, x86, assembly, intel

```
.386 
.model flat, stdcall 
option casemap:none ;
include \masm32\include\windows.inc ;
include \masm32\include\user32.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib

.data 
str_format db "count[%u]=%d",0
str_buffer db 256 dup (0)
msg db "Answer",0
n dd 4
m dd 5
a db 8
b db 45, -5, 2, -4, 1
  db 2, 14, -7, 12, 5
  db 26, 12, -8, 0, 6
  db 7, 8, 14, -4, 6
.code
start:
mov ebx,0
mov edi,0
mov ecx,n
t1:mov al,a
push ecx
mov ecx,m
mov esi,0
mov bl,0
t2: cmp al, b[ebx][esi]
jle t3
mov bl, b[ebx][esi]
t3:inc esi
loop t2
movsx edx,b[ebx][esi]
invoke wsprintf,ADDR str_buffer,ADDR str_format, edi,edx
invoke MessageBox,0,ADDR str_buffer, ADDR msg, MB_OK
add ebx,m
inc edi
pop ecx
loop t1
invoke ExitProcess, NULL
end start
```

Comment: Вопрос-то в чём?

Comment: Если a>xij, то вывести на экран результат

Comment: точнее количество элементов, которые удовлетворяют условию выше